# Problema al guardar decimales en sql server (ceros a partir del segundo decimal)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un error al guardar un numero con 3 decimales, cuando se va a guardar el valor en el codigo viaja normal tal cual yo lo paso en mi programa, pero cuando llega a base de datos a partir del segundo decimal me formatea los numeros en 0

por ejemplo le paso 0,543 o 0,549 y me los guarda como 0,540 a ambos

la columna donde van guardados los numeros es `decimal(12,3)`

tambien probe ampliar los decimales en base de datos pero a partir del 2do decimal me los formatea a 0

que podra ser?

este es el codigo cuando va a guardar en c#

```
public async Task<ObjTempData> GuardarValores(RepeticionesPesoViewModel viewModel)
        {
            var resultado = await _unitOfWork.ResultadoRepeticionesPeso.Get(x => x.Id == viewModel.Id)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if(resultado == null) return new ObjTempData {HasError = true,Message = "No se encontró el análisis."};

            viewModel = await CalcularValores(viewModel);

            Mapper.Map(viewModel, resultado);

            if(resultado.Promedio != null)
                await _unitOfWork.SolicitudSemillasAnalisis.GuardarResultado(
                        resultado.SolicitudSemillas.SolicitudID, resultado.RubroId,
                        resultado.Promedio.ToString());


            var guardado = await _unitOfWork.Complete() > 0;

            return new ObjTempData
            {
                HasError = !guardado,
                Message = guardado ? "Resultado guardado con éxito." : "Ha ocurrido un error"
            };
        }
```

y el metodo guardarResultado hace esto

```
 public async Task<ObjTempData> GuardarResultado(int solicitudId,int? ensayoId, string resultado)
        {
            var solicitud = await this.Get(x=> x.SolicitudID == solicitudId && x.EnsayoID == ensayoId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if(solicitud == null) return new ObjTempData {HasError = true,Message = "No se encontró el análisis para la solicitud"};

            solicitud.ResultadoAnalisis = resultado;
            solicitud.Finalizado = true;

            if (await this.Get(x => x.SolicitudID == solicitudId).AllAsync(x => x.Finalizado == true))
            {
                solicitud.SolicitudSemillas.EstadoId = (int) EstadoSolicitudEnum.Cerrada;
            }

            return new ObjTempData {HasError = false};
        }
```

el campo a guardar se llama repeticionEnPeso pero es incluso en ningun momento lo nombra, creo que lo hace a traves del mapper y cuando debugueo el mapper el valor que yo paso en repeticionesEnPeso es tal cual lo ingrese

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta el código del programa que intenta guardar.

Comment: en que parte tienes en problema? C# o en la tabla como estas pasando los datos??

Comment: ya esta incluido el codigo

Comment: No es claro cómo estás generando el Promedio, que puede ser realmente el problema.

Comment: En alguna parte se trunca antes de llegar a la columna. Revisa bien las longitudes en todos los pasos.

Comment: bueno al final el problema era que no habia actualizado el modelo, ya funciona correctamente